# How can I keep my background layer always locked?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background

1. The Background Layer is locked.
2. I duplicated the file to Background Copy.
3. Go to chop the Background Copy.
4. The locked background changes and no longer is locked.

Please help me reset my settings where the background layer stays locked at all times?

Comment: Chop? Do you mean "Crop"?

Answer (score 3):

You can only have one true Background layer at a time in a Photoshop document.

But you can lock a layer that has been duplicated from the background by...

1. Clicking the layer in the layers palette.

[image]

2. Click the lock button: [image]
3. Now both the original Background and the new one will be locked (indicated by the padlocks on the right side of the layers).

[image]